# How can I get permanent URL of images from Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud services to upload my image files. I need permanent url of images that I uploaded.

I use .service_url for getting URL of files but that links expires after 5 minutes. I try to set expires dates too long but it does not help. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a permanent link without middleware (I mean a system which catch your request and generate a temporary link for download), you can play with ACL and have this 3 solutions:

- If anonymous user can access to the objects, you can grant `allUsers` on your objects (or your bucket) to make it public.
- If only unknown authenticated user can access to the object, you can grant `allAuthenticated`  on your objects (or your bucket).
- If only known authenticated user can access to the object, you can grant then individually on your objects (or your bucket).

In all cases, the objects are accessible through this url `https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/path/to/file`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I granted permission for allUsers in my bucket but the problem is my links are valid only for five minutes. I need permanent URL's of images that I upload to use it.

Comment: This is your permanent link `https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/path/to/file`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

Setting public: true solves this issue in storages.yml

For more information: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#public-access